# Android: How to put custom elements on a circle/target

Tags: android, canvas, view, custom-controls

I need to create a sort of target and add objects to it, that have different colors and do different things when I click directly on them.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this? Maybe there is a library which I can use?

[image: circles on phone][image: circles with custom objects][image: selected item]

Comment: To me, this screams custom `ViewGroup`. Assuming you have some sort of positional data associated with the 'objects' (the balloon-like items), or a way of calculating that based on other properties, it shouldn't be too complicated either. Besides looking for a ready-for-use library, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

**The formal solution is**

Create `roundedshape.xml` inside `drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>

        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="4"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="5"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="#af08d7" />
            <size
                android:width="25dip"
                android:height="25dip"></size>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**Add `RelativeLayout` having `android:background="@drawable/roundedshape"`**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:padding="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedshape"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

**In your `Activity` add these codes to dynamically generate `ImageButtons` and add in `Layout`.**

```
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            ImageButton myImageButton = new ImageButton(this); //generate ImageButton
            myImageButton.setId(j); //Set Id of button
            //Generate Random Number to place ImageButtons in random position
            int min = 40;
            int max = 60;
            Random r = new Random();
            int randomNum = r.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;


            myImageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chatbox); //Set background of ImageButton
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
            params.leftMargin = randomNum+j*randomNum; //Generate left margin dynamically
            params.topMargin = randomNum +j*randomNum; //Generate right margin dynamically
            relativeLayout.addView(myImageButton, params); //Add view
            myImageButton.setOnClickListener(getButtonAndDoAction(myImageButton)); //Add OnClickListener
        }
```

**Add this method in `Activity` to handle the click event of your Image Buttons.**

```
View.OnClickListener getButtonAndDoAction(final ImageButton button)  {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button clicked" +button.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

**RESULT :**

[image]

**NOTE:** *I have added comments to make codes clear as possible*

Answer (score 0):

You could draw your image as:

1. Separate views - like in provided answer using `RelativeLayout`
2. [Draw on canvas](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)
3. Use opengl/existing graphics libraries.

It depends on your goals, maybe you need custom layout, maybe some sprites in your game or maybe bitmap to save into the file system.